# NSXMLParserErrorDomain while parsing an XML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, nsxmlparser

I am Getting a weird problem. I am making an App which should run on Both iOS 4 & 5.When i parse my XML in **iOS 5 It is doing great and i am getting my output**, but when i am Trying to do the same in **iOS 4 ,i am getting this error "NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 31**". in the

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError;
```

my XML is like this.. i need to parse the title tag within Item tag...

```
<item> <title> <![CDATA[ Cynical approach to tar my reputation: Army    Chief on leaked letter ]]> </title> <link> <![CDATA[ ]]> </link>    <guid isPermaLink="false"> <![CDATA[ ]]> </guid> </item> <item>    <title> <![CDATA[ Major fire in scrap godown in suburban Mumbai ]]>    </title> <link> <![CDATA[ ]]> </link> <guid isPermaLink="false">    <![CDATA[ ]]> </guid> </item>
```

My parsing code id this :-

```
-(void)parseBN{

    NSString *URL=@"My XML's URL";

    // convert the path to a proper NSURL
    NSURL *xmlURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
    CTNetworking *request= [CTNetworking requestWithUrl:xmlURL];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(startParse:)];
    [request startRequest];

}

-(void)startParse:(CTNetworking*)response{

    if (response.responseStatusCode == 200 && rssParser == nil) {
        [stories removeAllObjects];

        NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[response responseData] encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
        myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\"windows-1251\"" withString:@""];


        NSData* aData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


     //   NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];

        rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];
     //   rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[response responseData]];
        // Set self as the delegate of the parser so that it will receive the parser delegate methods callbacks.
        [rssParser setDelegate:self];

        // Depending on the XML document you're parsing
        [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
        [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
        [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

        [rssParser parse];
    }


}

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{   

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSString * errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unable to download story feed from web site (Error code %i )", [parseError code]];
    NSLog(@"error parsing XML: %@", errorString);

    UIAlertView * errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error loading content" message:errorString delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{    

It is not coming here.. so didn't paste the Inside code

}
```

I searched  in google for this error and everybody saying this error comes because of Unknown Encoding.. so i tried with "**NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding**" also instead of default Encoding.
Any Help will be Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it working...

```
NSString *myStr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[response responseData] encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding] autorelease];
    myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"encoding=\"windows-1251\"" withString:@""];
    myStr = [myStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"US-ASCII" withString:@"UTF-8"];
    NSData* aData = [myStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:aData];
    [rssParser setDelegate:self];
    [rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

    [rssParser parse];
```

Changed the Encoding type through NSString :)